# Eliminate the UserName from the "use" command

Tags: perl

All my Perl files start with the /home/UserName/lib use command. Is there a way to eliminate the hardcoded **UserName** from all my .pl files? I want to simplify duplicating of my website for different users and different domains. This is a Perl Templates website that takes the cfg=UserName param from the URL and renders the site according to the specific user format. But the lib files are all the same for all users!

Can you use something like this instead?      use lib './lib'; 
Sorry, I have very limited knowledge of perl programming.

Example:

```
use lib '/home/UserName/lib';
use RT::RealTime;
use RT::Site;
....
```

Anyone who can help is appreciated.

Comment: It might make more sense to add `export PERL5LIB="$HOME/lib"` to your login script than to use `use lib` with an absolute path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you use something like this instead? `use lib './lib';`

Almost, but not quite.

The problem with `use lib './lib';` is that it will look to the `lib/` directory underneath the user's current working directory when they run the script.  This means that the program will only work correctly if the user is in the correct directory when they run it.  It also creates a potential security issue if they happen to be in a directory where an attacker has created a malicious `lib/` subdirectory containing module files matching the names of modules your code uses.

Instead, the Perl idiom to do what you want is:

```
use FindBin '$RealBin';
use lib "$RealBin/lib";
```

When you use `FindBin`, it finds the file containing the Perl program you're running and sets `$RealBin` to the directory path where that file is located.  The `use lib` will then use the `lib/` directory under that path, regardless of what directory the program is started from.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm understanding your quest correctly, one way is

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $user_name;
BEGIN { $user_name = $ENV{USER} }

use lib "/home/$user_name/lib";

# use packages from that path...
```

This sets the username of the user who runs the script.

Better yet, *in this particular case* the use of [BEGIN](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) isn't really needed since [%ENV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) is a global variable set up by the interpreter early enough, so you can simply say

```
use lib "/home/$ENV{USER}/lib";
```

or

```
use lib "$ENV{HOME}/lib"
```

However, this won't work for many other related needs, which is why I (first) showed a way to work out things which aren't handed to us at compile time, in a `BEGIN` block.

In that case, the little dance around `BEGIN` goes as follows.  The `use` runs at compile-time, so `$user_name` must already be available; thus we set it up in a `BEGIN` block that must come *before* the `use` statement that uses the variable.  However, we need to declare the variable outside of the block (and `my` is a compile-time statement).

All that can then be wrapped in another block, enclosing code from before `my $user_name` to after `user lib...`, to scope that `$user_name` variable so that it is not seen in the rest of the file.

Another option seems to be to simply move those packages to a user-neutral location, and then you don't need the username in that `use lib`  statement ...?

Answer (score 2):

To include libraries from a directory relative to the current file, use [lib::relative](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative):

```
# in file /home/user/project/foo.pl
use lib::relative 'lib'; # includes /home/user/project/lib
use lib::relative '../lib'; # includes /home/user/lib
```

This will convert it to an absolute path, it's a bad idea to have relative paths in `@INC` since it relies on the current working directory, which could be anything and can be changed at any time.

lib::relative can also be easily replicated using core modules as documented.